# How to set up the relationship between an object and its view?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on an application where every object also has a view which is displayed to user. User uses this view to modify the object through click events.

My question is what is the most convenient way to setup the communication between an object's view and its underlying data ?

Currently, my objects extend the graphical package I am using in order to be able to use the click events so that they can be modified and also added to the view. Is there a better way to achieve this ? I know that I can use MVC/MVP but not really sure how I can apply it in a situation like this.

Comment: one option would be using angularjs and use routing there, but not sure about your specific implementation

Comment: Do you follow any design patterns like MVP? [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

Comment: See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19126358/643085)